# Time Stamp Parse Function

Tags: python-2.7, strptime

I am trying to parse a time stamp that comes in a very condensed format.  An example is "411201911516"
When I try to parse it with the function datetime.strptime(dt,"%m%d%Y%H%M%S") I get an incorrect date time of 2019-04-11 11:51:06
When the correct date time is 2019-04-11 11:05:16

I am running this with python 2.7 on Windows 10 
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The output you're trying to achieve will get from the below input since the input is not proper so it's giving the output. See below:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = '4112019110516' //( '41120191156')

datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(dt, '%m%d%Y%H%M%S')
print datetime_obj
```

**Output     2019-04-11 11:05:06**

```
 dt = '411201911516'

 datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(dt, '%m%d%Y%H%M%S')
 print datetime_obj
```

**Output 2019-04-11 11:51:06**

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the actual format of the time stamp.